# Store a value into a variable

Tags: postgresql

In a query, I am using the NOW() function several times (to extract the day, month, and year of the current date).
Is there a way to call the function just one time and save the output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression:

```
WITH date(now) AS (SELECT current_timestamp)
SELECT EXTRACT (year FROM now), EXTRACT (month FROM now)
FROM date;
```

But I doubt that it is worth the effort. The function is fairly cheap, and a simpler query that is easier to maintain is a good thing too.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [CURRENT_DATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) if you only want the date. Like most other date/time functions in postgres it returns the timestamp from the beginning of the transaction, so if you use it several times in a query it will always return the same value.

Besides, now() is declared as stable, so the optimizer is allowed to call it once for the entire query at the planning stage, and insert the result as a constant into the query. So it's not going to be called twice per row, in fact it's going to be called once for the whole query.

If now() is used in the WHERE clause this can result in optimized plans. For example you have a table with a "ts" timestamp column which is indexed. If you use "WHERE ts<now()-'1 DAY'::INTERVAL" to get records with recent timestamps, postgres will evaluate now() at the planning stage, propagate the constant, and choose between index or seq scan depending on what fraction of the table is expected to be selected.